# Industrial grade foreground/background separation in image processing

Tags: opencv, image-processing

My question may be not reasonable. But I like to know what is the real industrial grade foreground/background separation in image processing. My application is I need to extract objects from the background. It is easy to track moving foreground object in the successive images, but for the stationary image (just one image) rather than using the threshold, what else will be more efficient than thresholding?
Thanks

Comment: For the person who downvoted me, please give me a fair reason. What is wrong with my query? If you don't know just ignore it. If you think, doesn't make sense or my question has no benefit for anybody, please give me the reason. Just don't downvote with no reason. I think my question is fair enough and if I can have feedback from an expertise, it will benefit to other people as well.

Comment: i think what works is probably very application specific but you may want to take a lookt @ 1) try kmeans(2 cluster) clustering in lab color space and then apply a dithering algorithm. 2) active contours/level sets

Comment: @Zaw Lin: Hi thanks, kmean clustering is for which image? At the raw image stage, how to apply kmean?

Comment: @Zaw Lin: Oh yeah, interesting I see it in this link http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/examples.html;jsessionid=75c2efc94726c0417ce98f9d39d0?file=/products/demos/shipping/images/ipexhistology.html

Answer (score 1):

There are actually many other methods that you can try. Threshold is actually a pretty good method to extract object in my opinion. But if you like, there are actually many other methods you can consider depending on the scenario.

1)If background is fixed, you can just simply just try background subtraction. Whatever remains is the odd one out, in this case, the object you are trying to extract.

2)If the object you are trying to extract is something specific regardless of background, you can use feature extraction, classifiers(Haar for instance)

3)If the object have a specific shape, like circle, rectangle, you can use Hough alongside Canny, for instance, or shape detection, alot available on the web.

4)If the object you are trying to extract have a specific colour, you can take a look at HSV, LAB space, both which are much much better than RGB. You can also try to use pre-processing methods like watershed for example(got alot other more)

And many many many many others depending on scenarios. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an answer to your question but if the camera is stationary you can look at optical flow. This tracks a moving object in a video stream. It looks at the changes in the images and then can seperate the background and foreground.   [1]: http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/optical-flow.html

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks yes, that is for moving object in multiple images. But for a single image, I just want to extract objects. My thinking is edge detection and thresholding have to be applied.

Comment: There are multiple options. From what kind of image do you want to extract the object from? Color or Grayscale. If it it Grayscale edge detection is an option, If its a color image you could also use a SalientMap but it depends on the kind of picture and the kind of background.